# how do i run a docker command using crontab?

Tags: docker

I created a crontab with

```
*/1 * * * * /Users/sam/Desktop/file.sh
```

and the contents of file.sh

```
docker pull ---link of docker repo---
```

When I run file.sh individually it works fine, but the images are not pulled when I invoke using crontab, anyone faced the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Cron executes commands with different environment than normal, so when it runs your script there is probably no `docker` script in `PATH`.

Try this one:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

docker pull ---link of docker repo---
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be two issues.  The path (see Pawel above) and the user which is executing the cron job.

1)  You should always use absolute path in commands you intend to run as cron subprocess or redefine the PATH variable

2)  The user which has the cron job (the one you used to modify crontab) must be in the docker group.